# Adding image tag in Datatable

Tags: asp.net, datatable

I created a datatable I want to add Image Tag in that Datatable. My code is below:-

```
 DataTable DTflight = new DataTable();
    DataRow dr;
    DTflight.Columns.Add("AirLineName");

   for (int i = 0; i < distinctFlights.Count-1; i++)
    {
        dr = DTflight.NewRow();
        dr["AirLineName"] =distinctFlights[i].AirlinesImage;
        DTflight.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
```

I want to add Image Tag in my DataTable. Something like below if possible

```
dr["AirLineName"] ='<img src='+distinctFlights[i].AirlinesImage;
```

Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't think you'd need to do this. DataTable is for data. Whatever control you bind to the DataTable will have HTML markup.

Comment: Please tell me, how can I do it

Comment: What are you using to display the data? Repeater? Grid?

Comment: I am using GridView, but Autogenerate column is true

Comment: I haven't used GridView in a long time. Can't you just have something like `<asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="AirLineName"></asp:ImageField>` ? (though you may want to rename your datatable column to AirlinesImage). You should try to get the image working from the GridView code and if you have problems, update your question.

Comment: I have made many changes in DataTable, I have also done Pivoting in my DataTable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution

```
dr["AirLineName"] ="<img src=\"" + distinctFlights[i].AirlinesImage + "\" />";
```